# How to share a properties file across 2 different portlets in Liferay?

Tags: liferay, portlet

I want to create a common properties files which can be shared across 2 portlets in Liferay.
Or rather where can it be put so that all the portlets can access the same file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have two portlets in the same WAR then you can have a common property file for both in `WEB-INF/src` folder of your portlet and access it using `com.liferay.util.portlet.PortletProps` class like:

```
PortletProps.get("propertyName")
```

If your portlets are packaged in separate WARs then you have to place the property in `portal-ext.properties` and access the property using `com.liferay.portal.util.PropsUtil.get("propertyName")`.

Comment: But in my case, there was restriction that I was not allowed to use portal-ext.properties because they were common to all the portlets. So, what i did was accessed  the Properties file in first portlet that was loaded then saved it in session So that it can be accessed by all the other portlets.

Comment: Well that is not at all recommended. Session is just for one user. You dont have all the sessions (times the number of user accessing the site) having copy of the properties. What if session is invalidated. You have to bundle the portlets together in your case.

Comment: I cannot use **portal-ext properties**. In my case, if the session gets invalidated then the application will be redirected to the login page. Is there any other way around to share a property file across different portlets?